# Parametrizing Pytest fixtures with unique parameters

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to run the same set of tests on multiple fixtures, and for the fixtures to run through multiple different inputs, with the inputs being unique to each fixture.

My current code reduces down to something similar to this

```
FN_A_FILES = ['ab/x.txt','ab/y.txt','ab/z.txt']
FN_B_FILES = ['abcd/x.txt','abcd/y.txt','abcd/z.txt']

@pytest.fixture
def foo(request, fn_a, fn_b):
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', params=FN_A_FILES)
def fn_a(request):
    file_path = request.param[:3]
    file_name = request.param[3:]
    return [file_path, file_name]

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', params=FN_B_FILES)
def fn_b(request):
    file_path = request.param[:5]
    file_name = request.param[5:]
    return [file_path, file_name]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo', ['fn_a', 'fn_b'], indirect=True)
def test_foo(foo):
    assert '/' in foo[0]
    assert '.txt' in foo[1]
```

What I want to happen is test_foo to test

```
fn_a('ab/x.txt')
fn_a('ab/y.txt')
fn_a('ab/z.txt')
fn_b('abcd/x.txt')
fn_b('abcd/y.txt')
fn_b('abcd/z.txt')
```

As it stands, the code above seems to be running through many more tests than is necessary, so I think it's finding each permutation of (FN_A_FILES, FN_B_FILES), and then some on top of that; I can't quite make sense of the numbers in my head.

In my non-abstracted code, I have three lists of files, two with 3 files each, and one with 1. I have three fixtures (one per list), and one test_function that calls the fixtures. Somehow running this adds up to 27 different tests run, whereas I only want to run 7 (two fixtures with different sets of 3 inputs, and one fixture with 1 input).

Does anyone know how to set this up so that only the 6 tests are run?

Answer (score 0):

I would dodge fixtures to achieve what you are looking for and instead go for a simple `data driven` approach using `yield` to parametrize the test like this:

```
import pytest

FN_A_FILES = ['ab/x.txt','ab/y.txt','ab/z.txt']
FN_B_FILES = ['abcd/x.txt','abcd/y.txt','abcd/z.txt']

def test_data():
    for entry in FN_A_FILES:
        yield [entry[:3], entry[3:]]
    for entry in FN_B_FILES:
        yield [entry[:5], entry[5:]]

def bar(q):
    return f"{q[0]}-{q[1]}"
    

@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo', test_data(), ids=bar)
def test_foo(foo):
    assert '/' in foo[0]
    assert '.txt' in foo[1]
```

`ids=bar` is used to dynamically set test names to filenames from test data.
Running this test creates the following tests:

```
test_foo[ab/-x.txt]
test_foo[ab/-y.txt]
test_foo[ab/-z.txt]
test_foo[abcd/-x.txt]
test_foo[abcd/-y.txt]
test_foo[abcd/-z.txt]
```